# How can i get a count of a table(The table is a created table in a select) with a hardcoded value?

Tags: sql, stored-procedures

eg:

```
SELECT 'Table Storage' = 'D'
FROM TBS_STORAGE
```

How do i get a count of Table Storage where the value = D? (HARDCODED)

Comment: query will be SELECT count(*) from  
FROM TBS_STORAGE where `Table Storage` = 'D'

Comment: Add tag which db you are using and give more information for queries.

Answer (score 0):

You can use count to do that

```
select count(*) from TBS_STORAGE where Table Storage = 'D'
```

count(*) - gives the count of all the rows that satisfied the where condition

Comment: have you executed this query?

Comment: It was my typo!

Comment: I have a Stored Proc that does the below 

SELECT 
'Table Storage' = 'D',
'Table Name' = ts.Name,
'Table D Count' = ?
FROM TBS_STORAGE ts

So i want to get the count of 'Table Storage' Where 'Table Storage' = 'D'?

i tried your way i get 0 results but but i have results with 'D' in 'Table Storage'

Comment: @r_batra, I don't think it was just typo since you were not able to fix it yet

Comment: @Fahmi It was to mainly have a count and now stored proc is another add on to it, which is having issues, not a query :)

Comment: pardon, I'm new here, still getting the hang of it

Comment: @Fahmi, agreed, any other suggestions?